# Identifying an iPad/iPhone by Model Number

Tags: iphone, ipad

The model number of an iPad/iPhone can be determined by going to:

Settings app → General → About → Model Number

How to use this value (the one in `ML2I2KN/A` format) to determine the device type? It is an official model identifier from Apple, but how can one use it to identify their device? I didn't find any service of the kind at Apple's website.

If you tap on *Model Number* it will show another value - in format like `A1652`, and this value can help to find a general model at [Identify your iPad model](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201471) page (or [similar for iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201296)), but unlike `ML2I2KN/A` it cannot be used to determine color and storage capacity of the device.

There is 3-rd party service [Everyi](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/), but quite often it doesn't find anything. For example, searching for `ML2I2KN/A` gives nothing (*I know it's iPad Pro 12.9 from 2015, but that's not the point*).

Simply googling this value will highly likely result in some store's website with the correct item specification, and there is also this [wiki page](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models) with quite an impressive table of models.

But is there any  **Apple official** resource for this purpose?

Comment: I'd like to add that I use https://ipsw.me/device-finder to identify a device type based on its "A" number. Not official but an excellent resource though.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea (because why would I?) that you have to _tap_ the M model number to get the A model number.  This is _terrible_ design...

Answer (score 3):

You can check this site, some products can be found here. Hover mouse over the model, capacity and color will be displayed like this. It seems that Apple only wants to distribute this information within the company, there is no more public information.
 [image: ML2I2 IPAD PRO WI-FI CELL 128GB GRAY]`http://salesdownload.apple.com/public/sites/asw/common/compliance/Other_iPad.htm`

Answer (score 0):

Apple documents model numbers in their “how to identify” knowledge base / support web pages.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201296

Vendors and partners have more detailed / concise / complete documentation as well, but any recent phone should be readily searchable.

I’m not aware of any crowd sourcing resource that documents this better than your example but a Wikipedia list or developer or just an enthusiast might surely have done work to catalog these if you need a more complete / concise listing than what Apple provides publicly. (especially if you’re looking for a database that crosses product lines and geographies - there are many variants of devices when sold internationally with different software features / legal requirements around GPS chips and volume limits for example.

Comment: I already linked this page in my question, and also said that it doesn't help will looking by the model number in `ML2I2KN/A` format - which my question is about.

Comment: Yup -  And Apple doesn’t provide what you asked so I listed the most official document that’s as close as I know. If I’m wrong, that’s ok. I’m hoping it helps others as well.  I get if you don’t like the answer I provided - that’s why it’s still open for anyone else to contribute or even you should you find what you seek and wish to share. @retif

Comment: It's not that I don't like it, it's just not what I asked.